# If a system is defined in $n$-dimension then it has $n$ Lyapunov exponents

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chaos-theory, lyapunov-functions

I wanted to know if there is a formal proof to show that if a system is defined in $n$-dimension then it has $n$ Lyapunov exponents. Any links regarding information about this and Kaplan-Yorke dimension is appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate on what "a system" means in your Question.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. 1) Please only ask one question per question. 2) It is much easier to give you relevant information if you tell us what you already know. 3) What definition of Lyapunov exponents do you use? In many cases, the number of Lyapunov exponents being the number of dimensions would follow directly from that and the hard part is to show that certain invariances exist which allow us to talk of Lyapunov exponents of the system.